# Limit length of ListField in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, limit, mongoengine, listfield

Could I limit the length of a `ListField` data in mongoengie without `if` condition?

I need something like this:

```
list = db.ListField(IntField(), max_length = 24)
```

in my `document`.

Or I have to check the length of my list when it's going to be update and don't update it if the length of my list greater than 24!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing like this built into the `ListField`, but you can make your **custom `ListField`** providing a `max_length` attribute:

```
class MyListField(ListField):
    def __init__(self, max_length=None,  **kwargs):
        self.max_length = max_length
        super(MyListField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def validate(self, value):
        super(MyListField, self).validate(value)

        if self.max_length is not None and len(value) > self.max_length:
            self.error('Too many items in the list')
```

Comment: Just off the top of my head and not looking right now but cannot [SortedListField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.SortedListField) be applied with arguments that effictively do [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) as per normal MongoDB array operations?  I seem to vaguely remember a test case doing this. But if you can confirm that is not true then great.

Comment: wow I don't think about custom Listfield it seems great
but I can't understand some syntax like `**kwargs` and `super`  and `validate` functions 
could you tell me about them ?

Comment: @MDK sure, `super(MyListField, self).__init__(**kwargs)` would call the `ListField`'s `__init__()` method (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods), speaking about `**kwargs` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python. `Field.validate()` method is a base validation method for mongoengine fields, see for example how `StringField` is implemented. Hope that helps.

Comment: @NeilLunn from looking into [sources](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/dbe8357dd58fa9e2631d681f9e4528848ab74a48/mongoengine/fields.py#L757) I don't think that slicing is handled in a special way, but I might be wrong, my mongodb and mongoengine skills are very rusty at the moment :)